# Eilenberg-Moore Spectral Sequence for Homology with Coefficients in the Integers

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am trying to learn about the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence to compute homology and cohomology. I have been using Hatcher's book on spectral sequences and also McCleary's "A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences" but I am confused about the convergence of the sequence if we take coefficients in a ring, such as the integers, rather than a field. The two texts seem to use coefficients over a field.

Does the spectral sequence converge if we take ring coefficients?

Comment: maybe the problem is not the convergence, but rather that we do not have an isomorphism:

$$ \bigoplus_{p+q=n} E^r_{p, q} \sim H_n(E) $$

where $E$ is the total space of some fibration, the coefficients are in the relevant ring, and $r$ is sufficiently large.

In case the ring is a field, we always have such isomorphism, if the sequence converges